# Issue with push button on raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, pi-3, pi-2

I'm currently working with **Raspberry Pi**. I have implemented **push button(switch)** program using **python**. 
But, When I press the switch, then `if` condition is `true` and data stored but when I release the switch button my program is stuck. Why?

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

switch_1 = 17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(switch_1, IN.OUT)

while(True):
    sw1_status = GPIO.input(switch_1)

    print 'Switch_1 : ', sw1_status

    if sw1_status == True:
        print ('Data stored')
        while(sw1_status != 0): // here my program stuck.
            pass
```

Comment: This is pretty neat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your program is stuck because you have made an infinite loop in it. By the time you get to the `while(sw1_status != 0)` line, `sw1_status` is guaranteed to be `True`, and `True != 0` will always evaluate to `True`.

Perhaps you meant to wait until the button is released, in which case you want to update `sw1_status` in the loop, by replacing `pass` with `sw1_status = GPIO.input(switch_1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I have used

```
while((GPIO.input(switch_1)) == 1):
              pass
```

instead of

```
while(sw1_status != 0): // here my program stuck.
            pass
```

It's working fine.